# data-html2canvas-ignore="false" not working

Tags: typescript, jspdf, html2canvas

I am trying to hide an element before capturing based on condition. If I set `data-html2canvas-ignore='false'` then also its hiding that element. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Can you give a code example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @Valentin I wanted to hide some divs based on condition. html2canvas-ignore doesn't support that. I made use of ignoreElements property in js file. Working fine now.